# Copy data from ssh server to ssh server docker

Tags: docker, ssh, server

How can data be copied from ssh server and paste into docker's folder which is also in ssh server?

The docker cp command

```
docker cp filename container_id:destination
```

is not working for server and shows

```
Error: Path not specified.
```

but it works the other-way-round to copy data from docker to server:

```
docker cp docker_id:file name host_destination_folder
```

TIA

Comment: What version of docker?

Comment: Docker version 1.7.1,

Comment: You need to upgrade to a newer version, see the linked question for more details.